# Show that $\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} -z^xe^{-z} = 0$

Tags: limits

Let $x>0$ be a constant. Show that $\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} -z^xe^{-z} = 0$.

Do I apply L'hopital's rule here? It doesn't seem to help, for example, after one round of differentiating the numerator and denominator, I get $\frac{d}{dz} z^x = xz^{x-1}$ and $\frac{d}{dz}e^z = e^z$. I am unsure on how to proceed.

Comment: Is it $(-z)^x$ or $-(z^x)$?

Comment: Hint:$$z^xe^{-z}=x^x\left(\frac zxe^{-\frac zx}\right)^x$$Do you know how to evaluate$$\lim_{t\to\infty}te^{-t}$$where $t=z/x$?

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Suppose $x=1/2$. How can you apply L'H half of a time?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thanks, your hint is really elegant! Could you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Sure =) @elbarto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by showing with L'Hospital's that

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac t{e^t}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac1{e^t}=0$$

Now for any $x>0$, set $t=z/x$ to get

$$\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{z^x}{e^z}=\left[\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac z{e^{z/x}}\right]^x=\left[x\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac t{e^t}\right]^x=0$$

Answer (score 1):

let $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $m\ge x$ then $$0<\frac { { z }^{ x } }{ { e }^{ z } } \le { \frac { { z }^{ m } }{ { e }^{ z } } = }{ \left( \frac { z }{ \sqrt [ m ]{ { { e }^{ z } } }  }  \right)  }^{ m }={ \left( \frac { z }{ { b }^{ z } }  \right)  }^{ m }$$
where $b=\sqrt [ m ]{ e } >1$
Then we have  $$\\ 0<\frac { { z } }{ { b }^{ z } } =\frac { z }{ { \left( 1+\left( b-1 \right)  \right)  }^{ z } } =\frac { z }{ 1+z\left( b-1 \right) +\frac { z\left( z-1 \right)  }{ 2 } { \left( b-1 \right)  }^{ 2 }+...+{ \left( b-1 \right)  }^{ z } } <\frac { 2z }{ z\left( z-1 \right) { \left( b-1 \right)  }^{ 2 } } \overset { z\rightarrow \infty  }{ \longrightarrow 0 } \\ \\ $$
so we get $${ \left( \frac { z }{ { b }^{ z } }  \right)  }^{ m }\rightarrow 0$$,when $z\rightarrow \infty $

Comment: the statement says "show that.." so I showed

Comment: @pasabaporaqui If you are so concerned with L'H, please post your own answer instead of commenting on other answers...

Comment: @pasabaporaqui and that gives you no reason whatsoever to post L'H comments on non-L'H answers.

Answer (score 1):

i replace z with x(variable) and x with a(parameter) 
then we have $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} -x^ae^{-x} $

$\displaystyle x^ae^{-x}= \frac{e^{a\ln x}}{e^x}=e^{a\ln x-x}$

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} (a\ln x-x)=- \infty$

Comment: the second limit is not complex

Comment: the derivative of alnx tends to zero while -x in -1 so it goes in infinity

Comment: so the derivative of alnx-x tends to -1 and we are done

Answer (score 1):

let
$$L=\lim_{z\to \infty} z^xe^{-z}$$
Taking log
$$\ln L=\lim_{z\to \infty} -xz\ln z$$
Now 
$$\lim_{z\to \infty} z\ln z =\infty$$

> Thus \begin{align}\ln L=-x\infty\end{align} If $x\gt 0$ \begin{align}\ln L=-\infty\\ L=e^{-\infty}\\L=0\end{align}

Comment: If you would mind my editing the spoiler for you?

Comment: =) Hope that's what you had intended

Comment: Yes it would be great

Comment: I believe you meant to have $z\to\infty$.

Comment: Yes, and how do you do it?

Comment: Yes it is, a typo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65372/discussion-between-neonpokharkar-and-simply-beautiful-art).